# How to detect if a user changed their password and revoke the session on other devices?

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I have my own web service that performs the login of my application, everything works ok.

I would like to implement some type of listener that detects if the user changed the password. And where you have logged in to other devices, terminate and return them to the login page

For now, I created a timer that calls me to my provider's login method every 10 seconds but I think this is not the right way to do it.

```
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds:10), (Timer t) => loginProvider.checkSession(_prefs.email, _prefs.secret)
.timeout(const Duration (seconds:3), onTimeout : () => _onTimeOut());
```

What could be the best practice of this?

My web service is written in php.

Valid session response:

```
{
"status":"1", 
"userID":"1234"
}
```

Invalid session response:

```
{
"status":"2", 
"message":"Wrong email/password"
}
```

Comment: Best way is to check token on every request and whenever it's not valid anymore, send him back to login

Comment: You will have to keep some kind of token in the session and check if it is coherent with the token in the database on every request. Make it so that the token changes if the user changes his password, or request to be disconnected from all devices without changing it (a feature that some websites have). This token could be just the current `time()`.